# How do I make the time between dispensers longer and random?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have five dispensers shooting out chickens (it's for a minigame). I've been trying to figure out how to make them drop randomly and not so fast. The image below is my current set up... As you can see it's a mess...

[image: Minecraft redstone problem]

Please let me know if you can show me how to resolve this, or if you have any suggestions on how to improve this setup.

Answer (score 1):

#### Randomizer

There are two parts to this question. The first part is the randomization. The simplest way to randomize redstone is to use a dropper and a hopper pointing into each other. Use a comparator pointing out of the hopper and place *exactly* 2 or 3 pieces of redstone dust after it. Place a single non-stackable item (such as  a wooden sword) into the dropper, and add any number of different stackable items. The more stackable items you place, the less likely it is that the output (red wool) gets powered whenever you power the input (green wool).

The way this works is that the non-stackable item will take up 1/5 of the total space of the hopper, therefore the redstone signal strength will be 3 (1/5 of the max), which is enough to power the output. For a stackable item, the signal strength is only 1.

[image: Randomizer]

#### Clock

The second art is a good clock. For this issue, I suggest using an [Etho Hopper clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_clock#Multi-item_hopper_clock), which you can see at the top of the picture below.

It consists of two hoppers pointing into each other. Both have a comparator pointing into a solid block with redstone dust on top. Place sticky pistons on top of the comparator and add a redstone block in between. You can use virtually anything for your output, I used torches on the side.

Place items into one of the hoppers. The amount of items determines the clock timing (0.8 seconds per item), which can be as slow as once every 4.2 minutes.

#### Mockup

Here's a mockup of what it could look like for your system. The dispensers are below the granite blocks.

[image: Full Setup]

Comment: Let me replicate this and test it... I sorta get what you're saying but a lot of it is going over my head lol but this looks simple enough..I'll be back with an update!

Comment: [link] (http://gyazo.com/f80be183863dc684ed386629e5f71461)

I have it set up. What exactly do I need to put into the hoppers?

Comment: Accidentally, hit enter before I could finish.. Also, where would I put the button or lever to start the contraption quickly?

Comment: @Hush564 The clock takes any item, just chuck some dirt or cobblestone in there. To stop it, you'll need to power either the two blocks at the side, or power one of the pistons (in this case, it will finish the cycle before stopping). If you were asking about the randomizer hoppers, I suggest a single stone shovel and then something like a piece of dirt, a piece of cobble, etc., depending on the rate you'd like. If you place N stackable items, you have a 1 in N+1 chance to trigger.

Comment: Okay, to the best  of my knowledge I did what you recommended but I can't get the chickens to drop in a constant stream til the dispensers run out. The items that I put in the hoppers are a wood sword and some cobble. They just drop into the dropper and don't move.

Comment: I have continued to test this with no results. Is there a different design or solution that you can thoroughly explain?